# Converting number to words

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers-to-words

First it asks for user to input a number and it will convert it into words. For example:

```
104382426112
```

to

```
One Hundred Four Billion Three Hundred Eighty Two Million Four Hundred Twenty Six Thousand One Hundred Twelve
```

I follow some basic if else condition only to make it works. Here is the code:

```
def once(num):
    word = ''
    if num == '1':
        word = "One"
    if num == '2':
        word = "Two"
    if num == '3':
        word = "Three"
    if num == '4':
        word = "Four"
    if num == '5':
        word = "Five"
    if num == '6':
        word = "Six"
    if num == '7':
        word = "Seven"
    if num == '8':
        word = "Eight"
    if num == '9':
        word = "Nine"
    word = word.strip()
    return word

def ten(num):
    word = ''
    if num[0] == '1':
        if num[1] == '0':
            word = "Ten"
        if num[1] == '1':
            word = "Eleven"
        if num[1] == '2':
            word = "Twelve"
        if num[1] == '3':
            word = "Thirteen"
        if num[1] == '4':
            word = "Fourteen"
        if num[1] == '5':
            word = "Fifteen"
        if num[1] == '6':
            word = "Sixteen"
        if num[1] == '7':
            word = "Seventeen"
        if num[1] == '8':
            word = "Eighteen"
        if num[1] == '9':
            word = "Nineteen"
    else:
        text = once(num[1])
        if num[0] == '2':
            word = "Twenty"
        if num[0] == '3':
            word = "Thirty"
        if num[0] == '4':
            word = "Fourty"
        if num[0] == '5':
            word = "Fifty"
        if num[0] == '6':
            word = "Sixty"
        if num[0] == '7':
            word = "Seventy"
        if num[0] == '8':
            word = "Eighty"
        if num[0] == '9':
            word = "Ninety"
        word = word + " " + text
    word = word.strip()
    return word

def hundred(num):
    word = ''
    text = ten(num[1:])
    if num[0] == '1':
        word = "One"
    if num[0] == '2':
        word = "Two"
    if num[0] == '3':
        word = "Three"
    if num[0] == '4':
        word = "Four"
    if num[0] == '5':
        word = "Five"
    if num[0] == '6':
        word = "Six"
    if num[0] == '7':
        word = "Seven"
    if num[0] == '8':
        word = "Eight"
    if num[0] == '9':
        word = "Nine"
    if num[0] != '0':
        word = word + " Hundred "
    word = word + text
    word = word.strip()
    return word

def thousand(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 6:
        text = hundred(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 5:
        text = hundred(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 4:
        text = hundred(num[1:])
        if num[0] == '1':
            word = "One"
        if num[0] == '2':
            word = "Two"
        if num[0] == '3':
            word = "Three"
        if num[0] == '4':
            word = "Four"
        if num[0] == '5':
            word = "Five"
        if num[0] == '6':
            word = "Six"
        if num[0] == '7':
            word = "Seven"
        if num[0] == '8':
            word = "Eight"
        if num[0] == '9':
            word = "Nine"
        word = word + " Thousand "
    word = word + text
    if length == 6 or length == 5:
        word = pref + " Thousand " + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word

def million(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 9:
        text = thousand(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 8:
        text = thousand(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 7:
        text = thousand(num[1:])
        if num[0] == '1':
            word = "One"
        if num[0] == '2':
            word = "Two"
        if num[0] == '3':
            word = "Three"
        if num[0] == '4':
            word = "Four"
        if num[0] == '5':
            word = "Five"
        if num[0] == '6':
            word = "Six"
        if num[0] == '7':
            word = "Seven"
        if num[0] == '8':
            word = "Eight"
        if num[0] == '9':
            word = "Nine"
        word = word + " Million "
    word = word + text
    if length == 9 or length == 8:
        word = pref + " Million " + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word

def billion(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 12:
        text = million(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 11:
        text = million(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 10:
        text = million(num[1:])
        if num[0] == '1':
            word = "One"
        if num[0] == '2':
            word = "Two"
        if num[0] == '3':
            word = "Three"
        if num[0] == '4':
            word = "Four"
        if num[0] == '5':
            word = "Five"
        if num[0] == '6':
            word = "Six"
        if num[0] == '7':
            word = "Seven"
        if num[0] == '8':
            word = "Eight"
        if num[0] == '9':
            word = "Nine"
        word = word + " Billion "
    word = word + text
    if length == 12 or length == 11:
        word = pref + " Billion " + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word


#104382426112 One Hundred Four Billion Three Hundred Eighty Two Million Four Hundred Twenty Six Thousand One HUndred Twelve
test = int(input())
a = str(test)
leng = len(a)
if leng == 1:
    num = once(a)
if leng == 2:
    num = ten(a)
if leng == 3:
    num = hundred(a)
if leng > 3 and leng < 7:
    num = thousand(a)
if leng > 6 and leng < 10:
    num = million(a)
if leng > 9 and leng < 13:
    num = billion(a)
print (num)
```

Comment: Note that `n` needs to be defined.

Comment: Oh ya it was to make it works for more then one test case so. Should i remove the loop from the code now? or let it be there?

Comment: Just edit the code to set `n = 1` or something.

Comment: Do I need to edit it on the question asked above too, so other wont suggest to define n first?

Comment: No answers have been posted yet, so go ahead and edit the question so that the code is a runnable program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first step to improve your code:

Instead of

```
if num == '1':
    word = "One"
if num == '2':
    word = "Two"
if num == '3':
    word = "Three"
if num == '4':
    word = "Four"
if num == '5':
    word = "Five"
if num == '6':
    word = "Six"
if num == '7':
    word = "Seven"
if num == '8':
    word = "Eight"
if num == '9':
    word = "Nine"
```

you may use a list - and `num` (converted to integer) will become the index to that list. For example

```
ones = ['', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']

word = ones[int(num)]    # instead of "if num == '1': word = 'One' if num == '2' etc."
```

resulting to only `2` lines of the code (instead of `18`).
(And similarly for many of the other parts of your program).

---

To save repeatedly typing apostrophes (`'`) and commas (`,`) when filling your lists, e. g. in the same one as I just wrote

```
ones = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
```

you may use a common trick - first write them all into one string (delimiting them with 1 or more spaces)

```
'Zero One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine'
```

and then use the `.split()` method to create the list of individual words from it.
So you will obtain:

```
ones = 'Zero One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine'.split()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lots of `if` statements in your program and many repeats. You did use functions, which is good, but mostly your program is strait line code. There are several potential problems that I see.

The `input` statement should provide a prompt, `test = int(input('Enter a number: '))`. Casting the input to `int` will crash the program if user does not input an int. The program will also crash if the number is too large (a trillion) and no output if zero. The two solution would be to use the `try` and `except` statements or accept a string input and check for validity. The input variable `number` would be more descriptive than `test`.

The first three `def` statements, `once`, `ten` and `hundred` could be put in a dictionary in a `list` or `tulpe` format and a smaller program could provide the same information as all of the `if` statements.

The `thousand`, `million` and `billion` could be in a `list` and use the same dictionary as the hundred. The length of the number can be used for the starting point.

```
#example

#                       ten=0   ten=1     tens=2
#
one2hundred_dict = {0: ('Zero', 'Ten'),
                    1: ('One', 'Eleven'),
                    2: ('Two', 'Twelve', 'Twenty'),
                    3: ('Three', 'thirteen', 'Thirty'),
                    4: ('Four', 'Fourteen', 'Forty')}
                    #...

def two_digits(str_num):
    if len(str_num) == 1:
        ones = int(str_num[0])    # ones = rows
        tens = 0                  # tens = columns
    else:
        tens = int(str_num[0])
        ones = int(str_num[1])
    if tens == 0 or tens == 1:
        return one2hundred_dict[ones][tens]
    else:
        word = one2hundred_dict[tens][2]
        word += ' ' + one2hundred_dict[ones][0]
        return word

def three_digits(str_num):
    hundreds = int(str_num[0])
    if hundreds == 0:
        return two_digits((str_num)[-2:])
    tens_ones = str_num[1:]
    word = one2hundred_dict[hundreds][0] + ' ' + 'Hundred'
    if tens_ones != '00':
        word += ' ' + two_digits(tens_ones)
    return word

word_list = ['','Thousand','Million','Billion']
num = '104232423112'
#num = '100000023112'
#num = '23012'
#num = '4'
print(num)
Words = ''
if num == '0':
    Words = one2hundred_dict[0][0]
else:
    while len(num) > 0:
        while num[0] == '0':
            num = num[1:]
        indx = (len(num) -1) / 3
        pos = len(num) % 3
        if pos == 0:
            pos = 3
            word = three_digits(num[:pos]) + ' ' + word_list[indx]
        else:
            word = two_digits(num[:pos]) + ' ' + word_list[indx]
        if Words:
            Words += ' ' + word
        else:
            Words = word
        num = num[pos:]
print(Words)
print
```

Answer (score 2):

The identifier `once` is odd. It looks like you wanted to talk about the `ones` place. But your other identifiers are singular, so `one` would make the most sense.

Please replace your repetitive `if` statements with dictionaries. For example:

```
words = 'Zero One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine'
value_to_word = { val, word
                  for val, word in enumerate(words.split()) }
```

And then e.g. `assert value_to_word['Six'] == 6` would work.

Also, paying so much attention to length seems a bit unnatural. It is essentially log_10 of the number under consideration. You might instead choose to view this as a bookkeeping task, where you keep accounting for the portion of the number that has so far been translated to words. So after outputting "two thousand" you might use arithmetic subtraction

```
test -= 2000
```

to keep track of your remaining translation task (though I would name it `n` instead).  This would be helpful if a feature request asked you to support a switch that sometimes required seconds in an hour to come out as "three thousand six hundred" like you produce now, or alternatively to come out as "thirty-six hundred".

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [@MarianD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/142515/mariand) I remove the if condition with the list. And here is Some functional improved code.

```
one = ['', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
tenp = ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve', 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen', 'Fifteen', 'Sixteen', 'Seventeen', 'Eighteen', 'Nineteen']
tenp2 = ['', '', 'Twenty', 'Thirty', 'Forty', 'Fifty', 'Sixty', 'Seventy', 'Eighty', 'Ninety']


def once(num):
    global one
    word = ''
    word = one[int(num)]
    word = word.strip()
    return word


def ten(num):
    global tenp
    global tenp2
    word = ''
    if num[0] == '1':
        word = tenp[int(num[1])]
    else:
        text = once(num[1])
        word = tenp2[int(num[0])]
        word = word + " " + text
    word = word.strip()
    return word


def hundred(num):
    global one
    word = ''
    text = ten(num[1:])
    word = one[int(num[0])]
    if num[0] != '0':
        word = word + " Hundred "
    word = word + text
    word = word.strip()
    return word


def thousand(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 6:
        text = hundred(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 5:
        text = hundred(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 4:
        text = hundred(num[1:])
        word = one[int(num[0])]
    if num[0] != '0' or num[1] != '0' or num[2] != '0':
        word = word + " Thousand "
    word = word + text
    if length == 6 or length == 5:
        word = pref + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word


def million(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 9:
        text = thousand(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 8:
        text = thousand(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 7:
        text = thousand(num[1:])
        word = one[int(num[0])]
    if num[0] != '0' or num[1] != '0' or num[2] != '0' :
        word = word + " Million "
    word = word + text
    if length == 9 or length == 8:
        word = pref + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word


def billion(num):
    word = ''
    pref = ''
    text = ''
    length = len(num)
    if length == 12:
        text = million(num[3:])
        pref = hundred(num[:3])
    if length == 11:
        text = million(num[2:])
        pref = ten(num[:2])
    if length == 10:
        text = million(num[1:])
        word = one[int(num[0])]
    if num[0] != '0':
        word = word + " Billion "
    word = word + text
    if length == 12 or length == 11:
        word = pref + word
    word = word.strip()
    return word


# 104382426112 One Hundred Four Billion Three Hundred Eighty Two Million Four Hundred Twenty Six Thousand One HUndred Twelve

test = int(input())
a = str(test)
leng = len(a)
if leng == 1:
    if a == '0':
        num = 'Zero'
    else:
        num = once(a)
if leng == 2:
    num = ten(a)
if leng == 3:
    num = hundred(a)
if leng > 3 and leng < 7:
    num = thousand(a)
if leng > 6 and leng < 10:
    num = million(a)
if leng > 9 and leng < 13:
    num = billion(a)
print(num)
```

Comment: The `global` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: Oh ya!! Is it only needed when we need to alter the value on that global variable?